# Map from custom sql query to declarative table description

Tags: sqlalchemy

what is good approach to make custom sql query (plain SQL syntax, not mixing with Python) with known table layout and map it to declarative description.

Tnx.

Comment: You can use `session.execute("YOUR MYSQL QUERY")`

Comment: Ok, and how to map to already declared object?

Answer (score 0):

Good guy Jonathan Vanasco has answered this on sqlalchemy list,

If you have:

```
class MyTable(base):
   pass
```

You could do

```
session.query( MyTable ).from_statement()
```